# Tomcat images broken on Windows

Tags: linux, tomcat, tomcat7, hyper-v, ubuntu-15.04

I have a Tomcat server running on Linux. When viewing a png on Chrome in Windows, this image looks like this

http://imgur.com/x08QkUD in contrast the image on any Unix system: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXMn5.jpg

As you can see it is totally corrupted. Viewing the image in any Unix system it looks just fine (Without all those yellow weird lines).

If I look at this in Firefox (Windows), the browser response with "Cannot display this image because it contains errors"

Here is my request and response headers for this image (this is the same Response, Request as on a Unix system)

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:15432
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Tue, 01 Sep 2015 17:21:23 GMT
ETag:W/"15432-1441113486000"
Last-Modified:Tue, 01 Sep 2015 13:18:06 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request Headers
view source
Accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:148.251.217.3
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://148.251.217.3/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135
```

Is there anything that I can change in Tomcat to change this weird behavior?
I am thinking of mimetype, compression, ...

I have basically have the default configuration of Ubuntu 15.04 just now

Comment: Maybe I just add tthat my Ubuntu 15.04 is running in Hyper-V - could this cause any trouble like that?